# Is it possible to expand/merge different circuits?

Tags: programming, qiskit, ibm-q-experience

Suppose I have created a circuit composed of some registers with the usual

```
qc = QuantumCircuit(qr, cr)
```

where `qr` and `cr` are a quantum register and a classical register respectively.

Now, suppose that at this point I want to invoke a subroutine. This subroutine, however, uses some ancillas. Is there any functions to append this new set of qubits to the original circuit? Something like

```
ancillas = QuantumRegister(n, 'ancillas')
#qc.append(ancillas)
```

An equivalent problem (maybe) is the following one. Suppose I have a quantum circuit `qcn` composed of `n` qubits and a subroutine which returns another quantum circuit `qck` operating on `k` qubits, with `k > n`. Is it possible to compose the two circuits in such a way that the first `n` qubits on which the subroutine operates are the same of the original circuit?

At the moment, the only solution to me seems to declare in advance all the total number of qubits required (`k` in the previous case) and then passing around them to the various functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the first question, you can use

```
qc.add(ancillas)
```

Note that this will change to `add_registers` in Qiskit Terra 0.7.0.

Some more guidance on how to combine and extend circuits, you can see [this guide](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorial/blob/master/qiskit/terra/QuantumCircuits.ipynb). Note that this is for the upcoming 0.7.0 release, but you can already get the functionality with

```
pip install git+https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra.git
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed. Btw, there are any planes on when the 0.7.0 version will be officially out? Together with a list of major breaks wrt the 0.6 version.

Comment: I think it should be out in the next few weeks, but the holidays may lead to a slight delay. The 0.7 releases shouldn't differ too much from the 0.6 releases. They'll mainly differ to the integration of some tools from outside of Terra.